# Spark Dataframe Union giving duplicates

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a base dataset, and one of the columns is having null and not null values.
so I do:

```
val nonTrained_ds = base_ds.filter(col("col_name").isNull)
val trained_ds = base_ds.filter(col("col_name").isNotNull)
```

When I print that out, I get clear separate of rows. But when I do,

```
val combined_ds = nonTrained_ds.union(trained_ds)
```

I get duplicate records of rows from `nonTrained_ds`, and the strange thing is, rows from `trained_ds` are no longer in the combined ds.

Why does this happen?

the values of `trained_ds` are:

```
+----------+----------------+
|unique_no |      running_id|
+----------+----------------+
|0456700001|16              |
|0456700004|16              |
|0456700007|16              |
|0456700010|16              |
|0456700013|16              |
|0456700016|16              |
|0456700019|16              |
|0456700022|16              |
|0456700025|16              |
|0456700028|16              |
|0456700031|16              |
|0456700034|16              |
|0456700037|16              |
|0456700040|16              |
|0456700043|16              |
|0456700046|16              |
|0456700049|16              |
|0456700052|16              |
|0456700055|16              |
|0456700058|16              |
|0456700061|16              |
|0456700064|16              |
|0456700067|16              |
|0456700070|16              |
+----------+----------------+
```

the values of `nonTrained_ds` are:

```
+----------+----------------+
|unique_no |      running_id|
+----------+----------------+
|0456700002|null            |
|0456700003|null            |
|0456700005|null            |
|0456700006|null            |
|0456700008|null            |
|0456700009|null            |
|0456700011|null            |
|0456700012|null            |
|0456700014|null            |
|0456700015|null            |
|0456700017|null            |
|0456700018|null            |
|0456700020|null            |
|0456700021|null            |
|0456700023|null            |
|0456700024|null            |
|0456700026|null            |
|0456700027|null            |
|0456700029|null            |
|0456700030|null            |
|0456700032|null            |
|0456700033|null            |
|0456700035|null            |
|0456700036|null            |
|0456700038|null            |
|0456700039|null            |
|0456700041|null            |
|0456700042|null            |
|0456700044|null            |
|0456700045|null            |
|0456700047|null            |
|0456700048|null            |
|0456700050|null            |
|0456700051|null            |
|0456700053|null            |
|0456700054|null            |
|0456700056|null            |
|0456700057|null            |
|0456700059|null            |
|0456700060|null            |
|0456700062|null            |
|0456700063|null            |
|0456700065|null            |
|0456700066|null            |
|0456700068|null            |
|0456700069|null            |
|0456700071|null            |
|0456700072|null            |
+----------+----------------+
```

the values of the combined ds are:

```
+----------+----------------+
|unique_no |      running_id|
+----------+----------------+
|0456700002|null            |
|0456700003|null            |
|0456700005|null            |
|0456700006|null            |
|0456700008|null            |
|0456700009|null            |
|0456700011|null            |
|0456700012|null            |
|0456700014|null            |
|0456700015|null            |
|0456700017|null            |
|0456700018|null            |
|0456700020|null            |
|0456700021|null            |
|0456700023|null            |
|0456700024|null            |
|0456700026|null            |
|0456700027|null            |
|0456700029|null            |
|0456700030|null            |
|0456700032|null            |
|0456700033|null            |
|0456700035|null            |
|0456700036|null            |
|0456700038|null            |
|0456700039|null            |
|0456700041|null            |
|0456700042|null            |
|0456700044|null            |
|0456700045|null            |
|0456700047|null            |
|0456700048|null            |
|0456700050|null            |
|0456700051|null            |
|0456700053|null            |
|0456700054|null            |
|0456700056|null            |
|0456700057|null            |
|0456700059|null            |
|0456700060|null            |
|0456700062|null            |
|0456700063|null            |
|0456700065|null            |
|0456700066|null            |
|0456700068|null            |
|0456700069|null            |
|0456700071|null            |
|0456700072|null            |
|0456700002|16              |
|0456700005|16              |
|0456700008|16              |
|0456700011|16              |
|0456700014|16              |
|0456700017|16              |
|0456700020|16              |
|0456700023|16              |
|0456700026|16              |
|0456700029|16              |
|0456700032|16              |
|0456700035|16              |
|0456700038|16              |
|0456700041|16              |
|0456700044|16              |
|0456700047|16              |
|0456700050|16              |
|0456700053|16              |
|0456700056|16              |
|0456700059|16              |
|0456700062|16              |
|0456700065|16              |
|0456700068|16              |
|0456700071|16              |
+----------+----------------+
```

Comment: can you show the duplicated rows and the rows that are not combined? What I am guessing is that you are not visualizing whole dataset.

Comment: if you look at the combined dataset output, the value "0456700002" is appearing twice.

Comment: Not sure somebody marked down with "-1" to the question - if its ambiguous, please ask for clarity. if you look at the combined dataset, all rows having value "16" are duplicates of the first column from the "nonTrained_ds"

Comment: are those the only data that you have in the input dataframes? in trained_ds and nontrained_ds? or are there more?

Comment: there are lot other columns, but nothing has been modified in the middle. I am just extracting Dataset "A" into 2 datasets and joining them back to get Dataset "A". I am using Spark 2.0

Comment: I am not talking about the columns. I was asking are there more rows? All i want you to know and confirm that if there are more rows in trained_ds then there should be |0456700002|16  too in the data. so filter it and see if that is present. And I am sure that it should be there

Comment: sorry, no more rows, all the rows are displayed there.. in my base_ds i had a total of 72.. i verified those by outputting all.

Comment: are you 100 percent sure that there is no modification in the middle or that there are more rows in the dataframes (both)? I tried with the data you provided and its all fine. no such problem. did you try with the data you have provided in the question?

Comment: Yes 100%, though the DAG itself has some prior operations before the initial filter; and i did the explain plan. Its not doing SQL like Union.

Comment: Finally found, this worked! val nonTrained_ds = base_ds.filter(col("col_name").isNull).distinct()
val trained_ds = base_ds.filter(col("col_name").isNotNull).distinct()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick,

```
val nonTrained_ds = base_ds.filter(col("primary_offer_id").isNull).distinct()
    val trained_ds = base_ds.filter(col("primary_offer_id").isNotNull).distinct()
```